# Bootstrap 4 and jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-validate, bootstrap-4

I am working on a project and i need to add simple way to validate client side form then I moved to jQuery validation plugin. I play around some basic stuff, but I struggle when it make as this

[image]

So far I have done that much

[image]

My html code

```
        <body>
        <form id="default-register-user" method="POST" action="index.php">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="validationServer01">First name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationServer01" placeholder="First name" 
                    required name="fname">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="validationServer02">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationServer02" placeholder="Last name" required name="lname" minlength="4">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="validationServerUsername">Username</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend3">@</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationServerUsername" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend3"
                            required name="username">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#default-register-user").validate({
                        rules: {
                            lfname: {
                                required: true,
                                minlength: 5,
                                maxlength: 20
                            },
                            lname: {
                                required: true,
                                minlength: 5,
                                maxlength: 20
                            },
                            username: {
                                required: true,
                                minlength: 6,
                                maxlength: 25
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
```

I need to add

- Little message down the input field it is valid or invalid input
- Need to put green or red border around input field when it is valid or invalid

How can I improve this, and would someone explain how it works? I just searched the web and I found how to it with Bootstrap 3, but some class are change and need extra jQuery for it.

Thank you.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the Parsley jquery plugin does the same.
You can play with my fiddle here :

https://jsfiddle.net/djibe89/tu0ap111/

```
 // Parsley plugin initialization with tweaks to style Parsley for Bootstrap 4

 $("#my-form").parsley({

   errorClass: 'is-invalid text-danger',

   successClass: 'is-valid', // Comment this option if you don't want the field to become green when valid. Recommended in Google material design to prevent too many hints for user experience. Only report when a field is wrong.

   errorsWrapper: '<span class="form-text text-danger"></span>',

   errorTemplate: '<span></span>',

   trigger: 'change'

 }) /* If you want to validate fields right after page loading, just add this here : .validate()*/ ;

 // Parsley full doc is avalailable here : https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/
```

Comment: That is charm man! and Simple thanks

Comment: how can i use bootstrap 4 <div class="valid-feedback"></div> instead of span tag?

Comment: errorsWrapper: '<div class="invalid-feedback"></div>',